# Tracing pairs form a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a 4 list of pairs as

```
P1 = {{4, 17}, {19, 32}, {-5, 8}};
P2 = {{16, 29}, {31, 44}, {40, 53}};
P3 = {{55, 68}, {64, 77}, {79, 92}};
P4 = {{76, 89}, {88, 101}, {91, 104}};
```

and I combine this 4 list by

```
Q = Join[P1, P2, P3, P4]
```

and then i sort it with respect to first element in pairs b

```
Sort[Q, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
```

But I want to trace also the appearing pairs in last result with the corresponding list. That is `{-5, 8}` is came from `P1`. How to do this. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Many* ways to do this. Read the documentation re: associations, etc.
Here's a quick and simple way. Note I changed your symbols to lowercase initials (*bad* idea to use capital initials, risks clashing with built-in symbols). Since you do not specify if duplicate pairs can appear in multiple lists, I've not accounted for that, caveat lector...

```
p1 = {{4, 17}, {19, 32}, {-5, 8}};
p2 = {{16, 29}, {31, 44}, {40, 53}};
p3 = {{55, 68}, {64, 77}, {79, 92}};
p4 = {{76, 89}, {88, 101}, {91, 104}};
q = Join[p1, p2, p3, p4];
qs = SortBy[q, First];

(* here, strings are used to represent the symbols assigned to your lists *)
qs
qs /. Join @@ (Thread[ToExpression[#] -> #] & /@ {"p1", "p2", "p3","p4"})
(* put these "together" *)
Thread[%% -> %]
```

> {{-5, 8}, {4, 17}, {16, 29}, {19, 32}, {31, 44}, {40, 53}, {55, 68}, 
>     {64, 77}, {76, 89}, {79, 92}, {88, 101}, {91, 104}}
>
> {"p1", "p1", "p2", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p3", "p3", "p4", "p3", "p4", \
>   "p4"}
>
> {{-5, 8} -> "p1", {4, 17} -> "p1", {16, 29} -> "p2", {19, 32} -> "p1",
>   {31, 44} -> "p2", {40, 53} -> "p2", {55, 68} -> "p3", {64, 77} -> "p3", 
>   {76, 89} -> "p4", {79, 92} -> "p3", {88, 101} -> "p4", {91,104} -> "p4"}

Answer (score 3):

Consider initializing differently.

```
p[1] = {{4, 17}, {19, 32}, {-5, 8}};
p[2] = {{16, 29}, {31, 44}, {40, 53}};
p[3] = {{55, 68}, {64, 77}, {79, 92}};
p[4] = {{76, 89}, {88, 101}, {91, 104}};

SortBy[Join @@ Table[# -> i & /@ p[i], {i, 4}], First]

(* {{-5, 8} -> 1, {4, 17} -> 1, {16, 29} -> 2 ... *)
```

Comment: @Kuba I know first elements are obtained here by `#[[1,1]]&`, but isn't a pair of elements (via `First` only) compared by their first elements and on a tie by second? I don't know if OP needs were stated that precisely. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list with the list name and then `Sort`.

```
s1 = P1 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, "P1"}
s2 = P2 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, "P2"}
s3 = P3 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, "P3"}
s4 = P4 /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, "P4"}

Q1 = Join[s1, s2, s3, s4]
Q2 = Sort[Q1, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
Q3 = Q2[[All, {1, 2}]]
```

`Q2` will show the sorted list with list name and `Q3` will show only the elements.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers show, in order to "trace" the data you are sorting, you must, soon or late, build a new data structure where each data element "knows" where it comes from.

**1.** Something like: **`{{{4,17},"p1"}, {{19,32},"p1"}, ...`** is probably the simplest structure to deal with. You can directly apply `Sort` or `SortBy` on it. For example:

```
q={{{4, 17}, "p1"}, {{19, 32}, "p1"}, {{-5, 81}, "p1"}, {{16, 29}, "p2"},
 {{31, 44}, "p2"}, {{40, 53}, "p2"}};

SortBy[q,#[[1,1]]&]
```

> ```
> {{{-5, 81}, "p1"}, {{4, 17}, "p1"}, {{16, 29}, "p2"}, {{19, 32}, "p1"},
>  {{31, 44}, "p2"}, {{40, 53}, "p2"}}
> ```

If you can't or for some reasons you don't want to build such a list from the start, you can build it automatically from the existing definitions of `p1`, `p2` ... Here is a way to do it with this function:

```
tag[x_List, func_: List] := 
 Module[{symbols = ToString /@ Unevaluated /@ (Unevaluated@x)}, 
  Join @@ MapThread[Thread[func[##]] &, {ToExpression@#, #} &@symbols]]

SetAttributes[tag, HoldAll]
```

then for example:

```
p1 = {{4, 17}, {19, 32}, {-5, 81}};
p2 = {{16, 29}, {31, 44}, {40, 53}};

q = tag[{p1, p2}]
```

> ```
> {{{4, 17}, "p1"}, {{19, 32}, "p1"}, {{-5, 81}, "p1"}, {{16, 29}, "p2"},
>  {{31, 44}, "p2"}, {{40, 53}, "p2"}}
> ```

You can also build a "subscripted" form of the list with :

```
q = tag[{p1, p2}, Subscript]
```

> [image]

This form will work exactly the same way as previously with `Sort` or `SortBy` (*`SortBy[q,#[[1,1]]&]`*)

**2. `Dataset`**

This is most probably an overkill, but you might be interested in converting your data to a more structured **`Dataset`**. I let you explore the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and examples about it on this site and give you just an idea of how `Dataset` works. For example, let convert the previous `q` list to such a dataset:

```
q = tag[{p1, p2}];
ds = Dataset[
  AssociationThread @@@ Thread[{{"val", "symb"}, q}, List, {-1}]]
```

> [image]

Then, to sort by the the first element in the "val" column:

```
ds[SortBy[#val[[1]] &]]
(* or : SortBy[ds, #val[[1]] &] *)
```

> [image]

Then you can extract the column you want, chain with other action, ...